# Using page templates with php tags/code in it without eval()

Tags: php, templates

Basic page:

```
<?php
/* page options here */
require_once('init.php');
?>
<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            /* do stuff here */
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <content>
        <h1>Stuff</h1>
        <p>even more stuff</p>
        <?php echo('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'); ?>
    </content>
</body>
```

Base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $thing; ?>
    <!-- lots of header tags here whatever -->
    <!-- contents of <head> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class=container>
        <!-- contents of <content> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a basic templating engine with the syntax in "Basic page" above, right now I got it working with `eval()` which should be avoided.

It will parse through the file, extract the contents of `<head>` and `<content>` (or  if I'm not using this specific page type which has a container div)

- Contents of `<head>` will be appened to the `<head>` in the base template (see above)
- Contents of `<content>` will be placed inside the container div (see above)
- Anything php tags inside them should be parsed as php tags and not normal strings

Right now, I use this to place the content to where they should and include the base template's file:

```
function evil($content) {
    eval(' ?>'.$content.'<?php ');
}
```

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $thing; ?>
    <!-- lots of header tags here whatever -->
    <?php evil($page_head); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=container>
        <?php evil($page_content); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to do this, without the use of `eval()`, is this possible?

Comment: Why would not just use `include` or `require`? Is this content in a DB or something? what am I missing here?

Comment: The content is in a file, however I want to do that in this exact or at least similar format (see "basic page").

Comment: My personal recommendation is not to recreate anything. There are plenty of good PHP templating engines out there and you are best off using one of these. Have a look at Twig, Blade, Mustache, Smarty or Volt. Not being rude, just want to see you make a wise choice.

Comment: I'm not making another fully featured engine or anything, just something simple for a site I have. I have looked at Twig before, but it lacks one thing I want, being able to use PHP tags inside templates and the actual pages.

Comment: @POPCORNS: Why do you specifically need to use PHP tags? Most of the things you would need are in Twig, or can be added by extending it in the appropriate way (macro, function, filter, etc.). Plus you can sandbox it so the  that Twig templates coming form user input/DB only get a specific subset of functionality you deem safe.